# Is there a database of the geologic/stratigraphic units of France?

Tags: regional-geology, stratigraphy

Is there a page where I can look up rock unit definitions for France similar to:

- https://www.bgs.ac.uk/lexicon/home.cfm
- http://www.bgr.de/app/litholex/index.php

I did some searching for this, but because of my poor French I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I have been able to turn up is [the paid BD-logs service](http://www.brgm.eu/content/digital-data-products), which provides standardised lithology for borehole data. [Open Geospatial Consortium](http://www.opengeospatial.org/) data all appears to be listed on [the Geoservices page](http://infoterre.brgm.fr/geoservices-ogc), and does not appear to include a lithological database/lexicon. The [French Geological Reference Platform](http://www.brgm.eu/content/french-geological-reference-platform) does not appear to include a standalone database. The BRGM's [list of resources](http://www.brgm.eu/content/list-websites) also does not appear to provide pointers to any relevant information. Given that the FRGM is [in active development](http://www.brgm.eu/content/alsace-inaugurates-pilot-french-geological-reference-platform-rgf), it seems plausible that this is not in fact a dataset that currently exists.

Comment: Hurrah! Sorry I couldn't find any actual resources that did what you wanted.

Comment: At least now I have certainty and something to read. And it has the benefit that it improves my French reading skills, because I have to read the booklets that come with the survey maps.